# Macs unable to open shared files hosted on FreeNas because of temp files

Tags: files, freenas

We have a nfs share server (running FreeNas 11.2) mounted trough automount on which we store multiple *.xls files.

Since a few days, two MacBooks refuse to open those files with the following error message:

> "file.xls" is damaged and can't be opened. You should eject the disk.
>   "file.xls" is on the network volume "name_of_volume". Microsoft Excel
>   opened this network connection on 10 October 2018.

Every thing is ok on other Macbooks and worst, if I go through, `Excel > File open...` it works...

If I remove the temp files `._*` with a cronjob, it unlocks the situation but it's a temporary solution:
`find /mnt/raid/prod/ -type f -name "._*" -delete -print`

I have the same issue with the different extensions and same issue happens with `Preview.app` so it's not only with Microsoft Office.
I need to solve this and understand what is happening.

Comment: I had something similar happening once with SMB mounts and Microsoft Office in Windows. Office refused to open two XLS files, OpenOffice in the same computers worked well. It seems more something to do with Office than the OS. We never go down to the bottom of the question, as we were the networking team. At the time I suspected Office applicational locks, and you seem to have confirmed it.

Comment: Same issue happens with `Preview.app` so it's not only with Microsoft Office in this case. Thanks for your return.